# Как внедрить две модели из mongoose в service nestjs

Tags: nestjs

Как правильно внедрить partnerModel в linkService? - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получаю ошибку - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Ссылка на stackblitz - [https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/zharinov-nikita/nest-graphql](https://stackblitz.com/%7E/github.com/zharinov-nikita/nest-graphql)